# Not getting any response from pg-promise calls in Node app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I am learning how to use PostgreSQL in Node.js and pg-promise is one of the packages used in the tutorial I am following.  I have set up pg-promise in my code but when I try to run any CRUD operations I get no response.  The app does not hang, but none of the `console.log` statements I have for displaying results are executed either.

For example in the following code, the `console.log` statements in neither the `then` nor the `catch` are made and I don't see any other types of errors:

```
  db.any('SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4 FROM mytable;')
  .then(data => {
     console.log('Here is the data...');
     console.log(data);
   }) 
   .catch(err => {
     console.log('An error has occurred...');
     console.log(err);
   });
```

I am on a Windows 10 system and confirmed that the service is running.  Any suggestions on this are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It means you have a connectivity issue, and still trying to connect, so the rejection is taking time.

Comment: So what do I need to do to resolve?

Comment: Fix the connection.

Comment: Still not getting any? :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: I haven't looked at this over the weekend.  I don't know what I need to do to fix the connection.  I have reviewed the format for the connection string and I also tried passing in an object instead.  I get no errors in the console to point to what the issue might be,

Comment: You should test your connection via `psql` first ;)

Comment: I have tried connecting through the CLI and everything is working fine.

Comment: Do you still have the issue or have you resolved it?

Comment: I was never able to find a solution to this.

Comment: Sorry here. But it looks like a connectivity issue. Maybe wrong connection parameters being passed. You just need to do better diagnostics.